# Query execution slow when scaling DTUs in Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-scale

Am doing some POC with real-time scenarios for SaaS product to handle high volume of message, this will reach peak within few seconds(send/process) and listener side processing message then storing that computed data into Azure SQL Database(Separate Elastic Pool, 100 eDTU with Standard subscription), to mimic this am sending & processing message in parallel with few nodes and threads, in this case am facing some slowness in first few seconds of database operation when DTU reached maximum level the query execution is normal

- Is this expected behavior?
- What will happen if executes query during scaling of DTU?
- How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

When you scale up or down the service tier of an Azure SQL Database open transactions are rolled back, server logins may be disconnected, query plans may vary because the number of threads available for query changes, and the data cache and query cache will be cleared.

Since the data cache is empty, the first time you run a query it has to do a lot of physical IO, memory allocation raises and it's slow. You may take a look at queries performing slow and they may be showing the PAGEIOLATCH_SH and MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT waits and that corresponds to pages being pulled from disk to the buffer. The second time you run the query the data is stored on the data cache and it runs faster.

If the database faces high DTU usage for a good period of time throttling may see connection timeouts and poor performance on queries.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, am using just single db and single table with 4-5 columns also added necessary indexes on it(using simple insert and select query with high volume's, one app writes another one do read), running this set-up for 1hr duration and clean up table & queue messages before every start, am facing slowness on first few seconds only, after that working without any slowness, this happing when increasing DTU from min to max(15 - 30 secs), if it reached max query taking less time.

Comment: Examine what is the top wait when the queries are slow. http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0017.htm. If you see the waits I mentioned above (PAGEIOLATCH_SH and MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT waits ) then you know what is happening.

Comment: Investigated further on this, the category "Log Rate Governor" taking min and max respectively, "last_query_wait_time_ms" = 177 and "max_query_wait_time_ms" = 6015, am not sure which causing this, seems query have no issue, I guess something in scaling, immediate peak scaling/connection may cause this, but I don't know how to prove with some data points.